# How to add class to this form_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form_tag and I need to add a class to it.  Not sure how to do it without breaking it:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag session_path, :class => 'class_name' do %>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, html: { class: 'something' } do %>
```